# Hide Formula Results Until Data Is Entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm not very good with formulas, but I'm trying to use this formula below:

```
=IF($E18<17/24,0,$E18-17/24)*24-IF($D18>8/24,0,$D18-8/24)*24
```

The formula works well, but it keeps showing a result even though I have not entered data for E and D. How do I use this formula so that nothing shows up until data is entered into E and D?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to wrap your formula in another `IF` that will check if the cells are blank:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D18),ISBLANK(E18)),"",IF($E18<17/24,0,$E18-17/24)*24-IF($D18>8/24,0,$D18-8/24)*24)
```

The above will return `""` of either `D18` or `E18` are empty

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
=IF(OR($E18="",$D18=""),"",(IF($E18<17/24,0,$E18-17/24)*24-IF($D18>8/24,0,$D18-8/24)*24))
```